# Memory exception HashSet

Tags: c#, file, stream, load, hashset

I get an memory exception while loading a 4GB file. i have to do that twice but i have enougth memmory to load them. the memmory exception occures when i have 3gb left or more.:(.

Method:

```
public TableModel LoadTable(string path) {

        TableModel model = new TableModel();

        using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filestream, Encoding.UTF8)) {

                string line = "";
                bool isHeader = true;
                int counter = 0;
                List<string> rows = new List<string>();

                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {

                    if (isHeader) {
                        model.Columns = line.Split(new string[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        isHeader = false;
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        if (Settings.Default.RonudSet != 0) {
                            rows.Add(RoundDecimals(line));
                        } else {
                            rows.Add(line);
                        }
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
                model.RowCount = counter;
                model.ColumnsCount = model.Columns.Length;
                model.Keys = new HashSet<string>(rows);
            }
        }
        return model;
    }
```

Exception:

System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled
The function evaluation was disabled because of an out of memory exception.

TableModel:

```
class TableModel {

    private string tableName;
    private string[] columns;
    private HashSet<string> keys;

    public int ColumnsCount { get; set; }
    public int RowCount { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get { return tableName; } set { this.tableName = value; } }
    public string[] Columns { get { return columns; } set { this.columns = value; } }
    public HashSet<string> Keys { get { return keys; } set { this.keys = value; } }
}
```

Start Compare:

```
if (newFile.Name.Equals(currFile.Name)) {

                    FileLoader loader = new FileLoader();
                    TableModel newModel = loader.LoadTable(newFile.ToString());
                    TableModel currentModel = loader.LoadTable(currFile.ToString());
                    newModel.TableName = newFile.Name;
                    currentModel.TableName = currFile.Name;
                    new Compare(newModel, currentModel, currFile.Directory.Name);
                    break;
                }
```

Compare:

```
private void CheckColumns() {

        bool sameColumnCount = CheckColumnsCount();
        int counter = 0;
        currentContent = new HashSet<string>(currentModel.Columns);
        newContent = new HashSet<string>(newModel.Columns);

        foreach (string header in currentContent) {
            if (!newContent.Contains(header)) {
                headersNotFoundInN.Add(header);
            }
        }
        foreach (string header in newContent) {
            if (!currentContent.Contains(header)) {
                headersNotFoundInC.Add(header);
            }
        }
        if (currentModel.ColumnsCount == newModel.ColumnsCount) {
            for (int i = 0; i < currentModel.ColumnsCount; i++) {
                if (currentModel.Columns[i] == newModel.Columns[i]) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            if (counter == currentModel.ColumnsCount) {
                headerSequence = true;
            } else {
                headerSequence = false;
            }
        } else {
            headerSequence = false;
        }
        bool emptyNotFoundIn = false;
        if (headersNotFoundInC.Count == 0 && headersNotFoundInN.Count == 0) {

            emptyNotFoundIn = true;
        }
        ReportContent(sameColumnCount, headerSequence, emptyNotFoundIn);
    }
    private void CheckRows() {

        bool sameRowCount = CheckRowCount();
        currentContent = new HashSet<string>(currentModel.Keys);
        newContent = new HashSet<string>(newModel.Keys);

        foreach (string key in currentContent) {
            if (!newContent.Contains(key)) {

                rowNotFoundInN.Add(key);
            }
        }
        foreach (string key in newContent) {
            if (!currentContent.Contains(key)) {

                rowNotFoundInC.Add(key);
            }
        }
        bool emptyNotFoundIn = false;
        if (rowNotFoundInC.Count == 0 && rowNotFoundInN.Count == 0) {

            emptyNotFoundIn = true;
        }
        ReportContent(sameRowCount, emptyNotFoundIn);
    }
```

Its a table with many rows that i have to compare with a similar table. at the end i have to give a report about the diffrences. but i fail here where i have to load this massive file.

Comment: The solution will be to not store everything in memory. What informations do you really need?

Comment: Exception is thrown in while clausle, while adding line(row) to my table

Comment: Also, you say that it's a large table and that you have to compare that with another table. If you already use this term, why don't you use a database instead of large text-files?

Comment: @TimSchmelter the only question that i have is, why do i get a memmory exception when i have like 3gb left? please focus on code, because i haven't enougth time to create a db for this and so on.

Comment: @Ams1: the code doesn't help if i wanted to provide a betters solution because you return a `TableModel` that contains everything. I don't know in what way you want to compare these tables. If i would know it i could provide a different approach that needs less memory. Also, even if you think that you have 3GB left, you didn't have that memory at the time the exception was thrown. You know garbage collector

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Ok, let me update

Comment: 32Bit or 64Bit windows?

Comment: The issue is, you're loading too much data into memory. I think it's the 2GB per object limit in .NET. So maybe you can change your code not to load everything and do loading row by row and compare row by row.

Answer (score 0):

try using BufferedStream

using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(filestream))
{

}